# magento 1.9.2.3 after installed don't show category and product image

Tags: php, magento-1.9

I'm newbie in Magento and i'm testing the newest version 1.9.2.3. I added some products and categories just for testing this new version. The problem is, when i add a category and i upload a category image, that image don't show. This happened with products images too. I attached a image below to show the problem:

[Problem image - Magento 1.9.2.3](https://i.stack.imgur.com/xp4jM.png)

In this case, when i uploaded the product and category images, both are normal and the permission of "media" folder is 755. Does that problem is related with permissions? If so, what kind permission do i have to give?

Note: I installed this Magento version 1.9.2.3 using Cpanel and php v5.3.

Thanks a lot.

Comment: What are your base URLs for media?

Comment: Hi Robbie. Thanks for answered. Actually i added the category image via admin page like this image: http://s14.postimg.org/aq7rpijw1/Untitled_1.png. The "Media" folder it's located in "Magento/Media"

Answer (score 0):

I solved my problem. i changed the permissions to "755" in "Category" and "Product" folders, located in "HOME/media/catalog" and images appeared. If anyone knows other way to become this problem more secury, post here. Thanks :)